# py.test: get KeyboardInterrupt to call teardown

Tags: python, pytest

I am using py.test to write some tests and in my tests I utilize funcargs. These funcargs have their own setups and teardowns defined in the conftest.py like this:

**conftest.py:**

```
def pytest_funcarg__resource_name(request):
  def setup():
    # do setup
  def teardown():
    # do teardown
```

My problem is when someone uses CTRL+C to stop the test executions it leaves everything un-teardowned. 
I know there is a hook pytest_keyboard_interrupt but I dont know what to do from there.

Sorry for the noobish question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide a full example so maybe i am missing something.  But here is an example of how it can work, using the request.cached_setup() helper:

```
def pytest_funcarg__res(request):
    def setup():
        print "res-setup"
    def teardown(val):
        print "res-teardown"
    return request.cached_setup(setup, teardown)

def test_hello(res):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
```

If you run this with "py.test" you get:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.2.5.dev4
plugins: xdist, bugzilla, pep8, cache
collected 1 items

tmp/test_keyboardinterrupt.py res-setup
res-teardown


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! KeyboardInterrupt !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
/home/hpk/p/pytest/tmp/test_keyboardinterrupt.py:10: KeyboardInterrupt
```

which shows that setup and teardown are called if a KeyboardInterrupt occurs during test execution.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me find the source of the problem. My problem is when the `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised during `setup`. In that case `teardown` is not called. This is reasonable I guess, since `teardown` may remove stuff that is expected to have been created during the `setup` phase. But this may leave stuff in a dirty state. How do you deal with this?

Comment: @Parham: sounds like a good candidate for a new question post.