# Using the keyboard interrupt hook in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to catch keyboard interrupt so I can manually call tearDown. I know that this exists:

```
def pytest_keyboard_interrupt(excinfo):
    """ called for keyboard interrupt. """
```

from here: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html

However, I don't know how to use it/override it in my tests. I'm new to pytest.

Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create `conftest.py` file and override `pytest_keyboard_interrupt` in that file:

```
# content of conftest.py

def pytest_keyboard_interrupt(excinfo):
    # Calling tearDown.
```

**NOTE:** Not duplicate question, however answer may be use full for your case to: [py.test: get KeyboardInterrupt to call teardown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018265/py-test-get-keyboardinterrupt-to-call-teardown)

Comment: Yup, that worked for me. Thanks! Do you maybe know if I can get the instance of the class inside which the tests were running when the interrupt happened? For instance, I have class TestDummy with def test_dummy inside it. I hit Ctrl + C and end up in pytest_keyboard_interrupt. I still need to call teardown inside TestDummy. Can it be done?

Comment: @dnmh that's good question and my guess it deserves another SO question if you cannot find answer by own, I've realised that it would be difficult to access tearDown and place an note which may give you some glue ...

Comment: actually, what I can do is - mimic the behaviour the teardown does directly in this hook method. it's a few lines anyway, won't be much of a duplication - I'll just delete those resources directly.

Comment: @dnmh You could avoid code duplication by creating tear down in some "utils" file and reuse it over app ...